# How to only deploy dist folder to azure web site using .PublishSettings file

Tags: visual-studio, angular, azure, asp.net-core

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901842/how-to-only-deploy-dist-folder-to-azure-web-site) but fails, earlier use Git repository to deploy web app on Azure using  but now want to publish only dist folder using .publishSettings file with Visual Studio 2015 to overcome git command execution on gitbash. Project in .Net Core, Angular 2 with webpack. Try by editing .publishSettings like this

```
<publishData>
<publishProfile profileName="***** - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" publishUrl="****.scm.azurewebsites.net:443" msdeploySite="****" userName="$***" userPWD="****" destinationAppUrl="http://****.azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites">
  <databases />
</publishProfile>
<publishProfile profileName="***** - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://***-***-***.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot" ftpPassiveMode="True" userName="****\$****" userPWD="*******" destinationAppUrl="http://****.azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites">
  <databases />
</publishProfile>
<Target Name="MoveDistToRoot" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
<!--1.Deleting Folders except dist-->
<ItemGroup>
  <_FolderToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\src" />
  <!--you could add more folder paths as follows:-->
  <!--<_FolderToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\folderName" />-->
  <_FolderToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\refs" />
  <_FileToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\*.dll" />
  <_FileToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\web.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<RemoveDir Directories="@(_FolderToDelete)" />

<!--2.Copying files,folders from dist to root directory-->
<ItemGroup>
  <_FileToMove Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\dist\**" />
</ItemGroup>
<Move SourceFiles="%(_FileToMove.Identity)" DestinationFolder="$(_PackageTempDir)\%(RecursiveDir)" />

<!--3.Deleting the empty folder dist-->
<RemoveDir Directories="$(_PackageTempDir)\dist" />
</Target>
</publishData>
```

When Publish using File System folder structure look like this 
[image: folder structure]

and dist folder

[image: dist folder structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to only deploy dist folder to azure web site using .PublishSettings file

If you only want to deploy dist folder, you could right click this folder and choose Publish dist menu. It will only deploy the dist folder to your web server or folder which defined in the publish setting file.

[image]

Comment: Any updates? Have you tried my suggestions? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.